# How to use if else statement in email form?

Tags: c#, html, django, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a email form and this form is working. Now i want to add options for **subject field**. If subject is **cancel** then it should display cancel message something like **your service is cancelled** in **Message**(body) field. if the subject is **Welcome** then it should display welcome to our team message in **Message(body)** field.

```
<div class="container" style="background-color:powderblue; position:center">
    <form method="post" action="Form" style="background-color:powderblue; color:indianred">
        <span class="form-control-static" style="color:black"><h1>Email Form</h1></span>      

        <br />

        <span class="form-control-static">Receiver Email:</span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="receiverEmail" />
        <span class="form-control-static"> Subject:</span>
        <select name="SelectSubject"   value="Select Subject" id="ViewBy" class=" form-control">
            <option name="cancel"      value="Cancel">Cancel</option>
            <option name="welcome"     value="Welcome">Welcome</option>
        </select>
        <span class="form-control-static">Message</span>
        <textarea class="form-control" cols="8" rows="9" name="message"></textarea>

        <br />
        <br />

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send Email</button>    
    </form>
</div class="container">
```

Here is my Email Form code

```
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Form(string receiverEmail, string subject,  string message)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var senderemail = new MailAddress("test57697@gmail.com","Test Email");
                var receiveremail = new MailAddress(receiverEmail, "Receiver");
                var password = "Test111222";

                //From view
                var sub = subject;
                var body = message;
                //var sub = subject;
                //var body = message;



                var smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderemail.Address,password)
                };

                using (var mess = new MailMessage(senderemail, receiveremail)
                {
                    Subject = sub,
                    Body = body

            })

                {
                    smtp.Send(mess);

                }
                Response.Write("Message sent successfully!");
                return View();

            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Couldn't send email.";
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

}

Hi! I have another question now. I was using gmail server to send emails but now i want to use **django server**, C# instead of gmail. Any suggestions?

Comment: How is this related to [tag:c#]? Do you want to send this email through c#? If so, where's the email sending code?

Comment: Are you using any framework for the front? is this an asp mvc web app?

Comment: Yes I am using MVc.

Comment: Please don't post code as a comment as there is no formatting. Add it into your question.

Comment: you need to add onchange event to your select then call a javascript function, depending on the current selected option you set the desired value in the textarea. Do you use Jquery?

Comment: I never used it but i can try on textarea.

Comment: Why not just do the if statements in the Form action and change the body there?

Comment: @GeorgeB I tried if else statements in form too but it didnot work. May be the way I used it is wrong.

Comment: The answer posted by Rajesh is what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not proper which you written here some of them are missing anyway as per my understanding am giving one solution for your scenario.

//From view

```
var sub = subject;
if(sub.ToLower()=="cancel")
{
 var body= "your service is cancelled";
}
else
{
var body= "Welcome Message";
}
```

Comment: I added this code in my file but it didnot work. When I select Cancel / Welcome as a subject, it doent show anything in body.

Comment: @kimm My bad am sorry for that mess, Glad it worked and you identified. I have edited my answer and you have done Great work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rajesh. This is the right answer and it worked. I just deleted the last line.

```
                var sub = subject;
                var body = message;

                if (sub.ToLower() == "cancel")
                {
                     body = "your service is cancelled";
                }
                else
                {
                    body = "Welcome Message";
                }
```